# Drawing a polygon (Google Maps) and insert the coordinates on MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-maps, polygon, vertices

How can I draw a polygon (Google Maps) and insert the coordinates on MySQL?

Think the application must count how many vertices got the polygon.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this platform(sources) in your on system. http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

After that

```
INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES (POLYGON((14.4140625 48.45835188280866,50.9765625 48.45835188280866,35.859375 39.63953756436671,14.4140625 48.45835188280866)));
```